# How to fix my directory and possibly how to get folium module in python

Tags: python, module, package, folium

```
python setup.py install
```

the second line is what I get when I try to run the code in terminal

> python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

And if anyone can help setup the module folium in python, that will be great. It's why am going so much trouble. I have tried pip, conda. It works in pycharm, but I want the module to work alone when I open idle by itself.

Comment: pip or conda should work and is the preferred route.  I'm guessing you can do either with no error, but you're getting a `no module found` error in IDLE?  If thats true, you likely have two (or more) python installs.  One where you installed folium and one where IDLE runs

Answer (score 0):

You are executing command from a different path. It has 2 solution.

1. You move to that directory where the file setup.py exists and run the script.
2. Provide the complete path in command like

   python c:\temp\setup.py install

Comment: where this file exist and and how do i change the directory.

Comment: The path to the file setup.py you can open the folder containing that 'setup.py' file and copy the path from file explorer.